# Does qemu/KVM allow sound through Spice?

Tags: linux, audio, qemu, linux-kvm

I'm setting up a Windows 7 virtual machine to try and eliminate my physical partition. I have it installed and working with Spice and the drivers from the fedora site:

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Windows_Virtio_Drivers#Direct_download

When I connect via Spice, I can connect and see the video pretty quickly. However, I don't hear any sound. If I put in the soundhw option, it no longer runs as a daemon where I can connect to Spice.

Does Spice not pass through sound or am I doing something wrong?

My command line for the emulation:

```
#!/bin/bash

#-monitor stdio \

SPICE_PORT=5924

qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -daemonize \
    -enable-kvm \
        -cpu host \
        -drive file=/home/mike/underling.img,if=virtio \
        -net nic,model=virtio -net user,hostname=underling \
        -m 4G \
        -name Underling \
    -usbdevice tablet \
    -device virtio-serial \
    -chardev spicevmc,id=vdagent,name=vdagent \
    -device virtserialport,chardev=vdagent,name=com.redhat.spice.0 \
    -vga qxl \
    -spice port=${SPICE_PORT},disable-ticketing \
        "$@"
exec spicec --title Underling -h 127.0.0.1 -p ${SPICE_PORT}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Spice certainly DOES allow sound passthrough. My issue was that I had put -soundhw hda without putting a \ after it. So now it finally works with the audio passthrough with Spice and here is my run shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#-monitor stdio \

SPICE_PORT=5924

qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -daemonize \
    -enable-kvm \
        -cpu host \
        -drive file=/home/mike/underling.img,if=virtio \
        -net nic,model=virtio -net user,hostname=underling \
        -m 4G \
    -soundhw hda \
        -name Underling \
    -usbdevice tablet \
    -device virtio-serial \
    -chardev spicevmc,id=vdagent,name=vdagent \
    -device virtserialport,chardev=vdagent,name=com.redhat.spice.0 \
    -vga qxl \
    -spice port=${SPICE_PORT},disable-ticketing \
        "$@"
exec spicec --title Underling -h 127.0.0.1 -p ${SPICE_PORT}
```